# R: Read in a subset of lines and turn it into a conventional format (data.table approach preferred)

Tags: r, types, import, data.table, delimiter

I have a file that that has over a hundred million rows and scattered throughout there are extra tab delimiters in fields. I need to read the problematic rows into R whilst ignoring the others due to the large file size involved.

Example txt file with extra delimiters in some rows:

```
text_file <-"My\tname\tis\tAlpha\nMy\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo\nMy\tname\tis\tCharlie\nMy\tname\tis\t\t\tDelta\nMy\tname\tis\tEcho"
```

The first thing that I tried was using the 'readLines' function however whilst I can specify the row to stop on it will still read everything else up to that point which could still be too much

```
readLines(textConnection(text_file), n = 4)

[1] "My\tname\tis\tAlpha"     "My\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo" "My\tname\tis\tCharlie"   "My\tname\tis\t\t\tDelta"
```

I then realised that I could also use the other dataset import functions if I specified the delimiter to be something that should probably never appear. The "fread" function from the data.table package would be perfect for this as it is the fastest way to deal with large datasets like mine however when I tried it the data was in a format that I couldnt really work with further:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

lines <- fread(text_file, sep = NULL, header = FALSE, skip = 1, nrows = 3)

> lines
                        V1
1: My\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo
2:   My\tname\tis\tCharlie
3: My\tname\tis\t\t\tDelta

> invalid_delimiter_rows <- which(stri_count_regex(lines, "\\t") != 3)
Warning message:
In stri_count_regex(lines, "\\t") :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing
```

Preferably I shouldnt have to convert this data after importing however when I tried changing this to a character vector or list it was still in a bad format (the concatenation is considered part of the string and not a function). What is the most computing time efficient way that I could approach this issue?

```
> class(lines)

[1] "data.table" "data.frame"

> as.character(lines)

[1] "c(\"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tBravo\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tCharlie\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tDelta\")"
```

Comment: Using `fread` with your separetor and setting `fill` TRUE? `fill 
logical (default is FALSE). If TRUE then in case the rows have unequal length, blank fields are implicitly filled.`

Comment: I want to keep it in the lines format so that I can use the 'sub' function to eliminate any extra delimiters and write it back out again to be inserted into SQL. It seems that setting fill = TRUE keeps it as a data frame/table and creates empty fields at each extra delimiter, not sure how I can fix the problem from here in a faster way than editing the lines directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's replicate the process till `fread()` import:

```
# your example string
text_file <-"My\tname\tis\tAlpha\nMy\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo\nMy\tname\tis\tCharlie\nMy\tname\tis\t\t\tDelta\nMy\tname\tis\tEcho"

# import
library(data.table)
lines <- fread(text_file, sep = NULL, header = FALSE, skip = 1, nrows = 5)
lines
                        V1
1: My\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo
2:   My\tname\tis\tCharlie
3: My\tname\tis\t\t\tDelta
4:      My\tname\tis\tEcho
```

When you try

```
as.character(lines)
[1] "c(\"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tBravo\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tCharlie\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tDelta\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tEcho\")"
```

it converts all `data.table` in character, so each column will be a concatenated vector. See below:

```
as.character(data.table(lines$V1, lines$V1))
[1] "c(\"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tBravo\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tCharlie\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tDelta\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tEcho\")"
[2] "c(\"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tBravo\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tCharlie\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\t\\t\\tDelta\", \"My\\tname\\tis\\tEcho\")"
```

What you want is extract just `lines$V1`, which is already a character vector.

```
lines$V1
[1] "My\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo" "My\tname\tis\tCharlie"   "My\tname\tis\t\t\tDelta" "My\tname\tis\tEcho"
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, I created the text_file variable to mimic my real scenario of a completely separate file sitting outside the R environment that needs to be read in first before we can edit it. Unfortunately the problem currently is that when you import the file, it gets assigned a strange class type that is not easy to edit - this is what I'm wanting to fix!  Also on another note - we need to keep some of the tab delimiters as they split up the data into new columns so we cant use gsub here, I've got this portion of the code all set up though so it's only the first part I need help with

Comment: As an example - I'd want to turn the line "My\tname\tis\t\t\tBravo" which has five tabs into "My\tname\tis\tBravo" with 3 tab delimiters so it matches up with the rest of the data. Gsub will get rid of all delimiters causing all the data to be bunched up into one column (In my real situation I have 40 columns). I need to read it into R so that I can use my code to get rid of the {n'th} occurence of a tab so that the row matches up with the rest of the data

Comment: I'm an idiot... After reading the later part of your answer I realised that all I needed was: lines <- lines$V1 after I've used the fread function. If you edit your answer with this at the top I'll accept it

Comment: haha No, man. We are. I realize now that i never really understood what you were looking for. But it's great to know, at least, that my confusion helped you to reach your needs. Edition made :)